# Network-Downstream falls to zero every other second

Tags: networking, windows-10

My network works rather fine, but as soon as I try to do something that requires constant connection, (I.e. streaming a video) I have problems doing so.

After checking my task-manager I saw that the network-downstream keeps breaking to 0Kbps...

Why is that? Could it be a virus? The network connection is never disconnected.

Network performance:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you called "constant connection" refers to a high and constant downstream load on the Internet connection towards your home network (LAN). If so, Internet Service Providers (ISP) make use of what is called traffic shaping which, among other things, is used for bandwidth limiting purposes. Your graph shows what seems to be traffic shaping but a very horrible one. To check if the problem is on your ISP, your router or your host you can:
1) Set another host on your network and transfer a big file (a film) between them. Should you observe the same pattern then you have a problem with either your LAN or with your host. To discard the router/switch you could connect both hosts back-to-back with an Ethernet crossover cable (assign IPs manually e.g. 192.168.0.1 host-1 and 192.168.0.2 host-2 both with network mask 255.255.255.0). Should you find the same pattern, then you have problems with one of the hosts or in worst case with both.
2) If previous point is fine that is, you do not find any strange pattern but an steady one then there are two options left: either your ISP or your router capabilities to route traffic from the Internet interface into your LAN. To check the router then you would need to set a host on the WAN interface of the router with a DCHP server, proper IP network configuration and a FTP server. This scenario becomes much complicated to test in order to discard or to confirm the router. The third option would be to call the ISP and ask them for the traffic shaping policy (good luck).

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer. I will look into that as soon as possible.